# Union of a chain of cardinalities?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I was trying to understand the union of a chain of cardinalities and I found this equation
$$\kappa=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa} \alpha$$ for any cardinal $\kappa$ in the answers to this question.

[Can every set be expressed as the union of a chain of sets of lesser cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605313/can-every-set-be-expressed-as-the-union-of-a-chain-of-sets-of-lesser-cardinality)

I dont understand how this could be possible if we assume there
is no cardinality between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$.

In general, for any given cardinal $\kappa$, is there an expression
for $$\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa} \alpha$$

Comment: I think the $\alpha$'s are supposed to be ordinals, not cardinals.

Answer (score 1):

In the answers to the question, $\alpha$ is an ordinal smaller than $\kappa$, not a cardinal. Regardless to the continuum hypothesis you are correct that the only cardinals smaller than $\omega_1$ are finite and $\omega$.

But as an ordinal, $\omega_1$ is the increasing union of countable ordinals.

Comment: I see, so does this mean that for any ordinal $\kappa$ (not necessarily a cardinal) we get $$\kappa=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}\alpha$$?

Comment: Every *limit* ordinal is the union of all the smaller ordinals. This entire thing is not true for successor ordinals, so in particular for finite *cardinals* this is false. $\bigcup_{\alpha<2}\alpha=1$.